# Acessing ViewData in javascript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to access view data In Java script in following code

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(MyModel _MyModel)
{
    //some Code

    if (true..)
    {
            ViewData["Messages"] = "Data Updated Sucessfully";
    }
        else
    {
        ViewData["Messages"] = "you cannot Updated data";
    }

    return View();
}
```

In javascript

```
function SaveData() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        //          $('#divLoadImage').show();
        //            $('#divOverlay').show();
        //   debugger;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Admin/Edit/",
            data: "",
            complete: function () {
                alert(ViewData["Messages"]);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

it give me no value in alert..

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, also can you try to format your code better?

Answer (score 4):

You need to encode it using for example the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class:

```
function SaveData() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Admin/Edit/",
            data: "",
            complete: function () {
                alert(@Html.Raw(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["Messages"])));
            }
        });

    });
}
```

or use simple quotes but be careful as this might break if the message contains quote so I wouldn't recommend you this:

```
alert('@ViewData["Messages"]');
```